# Getting key value pairs from json reponse into angular js

Tags: angularjs

How do I map the json response to the table in html page.

Angularjs Controller:

```
app.controller('tableController', function ($scope,$http)
            {
                $scope.customerTable = [];
                $scope.getTable = function ()
                {
                    $http.get('<%=request.getContextPath()%>/GetTable.do').success(function (data)
                    {
                        $scope.customerTable = data;
//                        console.log($scope.customerTable);
                    });
                };
            });
```

html code:

```
 <div ng-controller="tableController">
                <!--<p>Click <a ng-click="getTable()">here</a> to load data.</p>-->
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Card Number</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Opening Balance</th>
                        <th>Withdrawal</th>
                        <th>Deposit</th>
                        <th>Closing Balance</th>
                        <th>Tx Date</th>
                        <th>Usage_Type</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable ">
                        <td>{{data[0]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <button class="form-control btn btn-success" type="submit" ng-click="getTable()">Load Table Data</button>
            </div>
```

The response is in one array with key, value pairs. Do I have to modify the ng-repeat?

Here is the json response:

```
[{"TXDATE":"1-Aug-14","FIRST_NAME":"MOSES","USAGE_TYPE":"HOTELS/MOTELS/RESORTS","WITHDRAWAL":"15200","DEPOSIT":"0","CARD_NUMBER":"AL98****66325","CLOSING_BAL":"-362764.96","OPENING_BALANCE":"0"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fields in every object:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable ">
     <th>{{data.FIRST_NAME}}</th>
     <th>{{data.CARD_NUMBER}}</th>
     ...
</tr>
```

Perhaps you could use a [directive](http://ui-grid.info/) for this kind of table related iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the attributes. it should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable ">
   <td>{{data.TXDATE}}</td> <!-- result: 1-Aug-14 -->
</tr>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to modify it.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in customerTable ">
    <td>{{data['CARD_NUMBER']}}</td>
    <td>{{data['TXDATE']}}</td>
    <td>{{data['OPENING_BALANCE']}}</td>
    ...
</tr>
```